# Recursively calling function on certain condition

Tags: python, recursion

I have a function that extracts the content from a random website every time using beautifulsoup library where I get random content every time. I'm successfully able to extract the content..... but let's say (if the output text is 'abc'). I want to re-call the function again and again until I get a different output. I added an if condition to make it done but somehow it's not working as I thought:

```
class MyClass:

    def get_comment(self):
        source = requests.get('https://www.example.com/random').text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
        comment = soup.find('div', class_='commentMessage').span.text
        if comment == "abc":
            logging.warning('Executing again....')
            self.get_comment() #Problem here....Not executing again
        return comment

mine = MyClass()
mine.get_comment() # I get 'abc' output
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call your function recursively you aren't doing anything with the output:

```
class MyClass:

    def get_comment(self):
        source = requests.get('https://www.example.com/random').text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
        comment = soup.find('div', class_='commentMessage').span.text
        if comment == "abc":
            logging.warning('Executing again....')
            return self.get_comment() #Call the method again, AND return result from that call
        else:
            return comment #return unchanged

mine = MyClass()
mine.get_comment()
```

I think this should be more like what you're after.